# How to launch iframe in my case?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to launch an iframe with Angular JS.

I have something like

JS

```
$scope.loadIframe = function() {
    $scope.currentProjectUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('http://test.com/' + ID);
}
```

In my html

```
<a ng-click="loadIframe()">
   <iframe ng-src="{{currentProjectUrl}}"> </iframe>
</a>
```

My currrent setup is iframe always exists in the page, but I want to load iframe 'After' user clicks the link. Is there anyway to do this? Thanks.

Comment: I highly doubt that `iframe` is a valid child of `<a>`

Answer (score 0):

please see here http://jsbin.com/qujeke/1/edit?html,js,output
just use ng-show/hide directive

```
  <a ng-click="loadIframe()" ng-hide="currentProjectUrl">Load Frame </a>
   <iframe ng-src="{{currentProjectUrl}}" ng-show="currentProjectUrl" > </iframe>
```